# Basic question about Mathematica's number notation

Tags: differential-equations, notation

[image]

I am using Mathematica solve equations, and there's one thing I am finding counterintuitive to understand. When I solve an equation, why do numbers look like this? What does ` mean after a number? So for example, the first number: 1.`, does it mean it is very close to 1 or it converges to 1? if that's the case, why is 0.66666666665` not displayed similiarly?

Comment: What input produced this output?

Comment: A backtick as shown above indicates a machine-precision (floating-point) number.  A backtick followed by a number (not shown) indicates an arbitrary-precision number (e.g. ``0.8414709848078965067`7.192402324441726``, which is the result of ``Sin[1.`7]``). It's in the documention [Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html) under "Numerical Precision".

Comment: What exactly is the difference machine-precision and arbitrary-precision? For example if we look at 2.` Does it mean it is very close to 2, but has a very lange number of significant figures, but it does not show them? 

If I simplify 0.6666665` with 0.666, would I be making a critical mistake? For sure I'd be losing some precision, but that level of precision is not necessary for me.

Comment: `difference machine-precision and arbitrary-precision?` machine precision means whatever the hardware  precision supports. typically 15 significant figures for double float which is standard.  arbitrary-precision means whatever you ask for. (done in software emulation).  compare output of 2.1234567890123456789012345678``   to 2.1234567890123456789012345678``100  (had to write two ticks here, because stackexchange  formatting gets in the way)

Comment: ``2.` `` is the floating-point number for two. It is exactly two, because the FP format can represent two exactly. OTOH, ``0.6666665` `` is `3002399000980393/2^52` (exactly, in the FP format) and ``0.666` `` is `5998794703657501/2^53`, and their difference is approximately `0.0006665`. Mathematica does not print the trailing zeros of ``2.` `` in output. However, `RealDigits[2.]` will show all significant digits of a floating-point number. [Goldberg](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/103162.103163) is a standard introductory reference on FP, and you can google it to find several PDF copies online